# Ошибка в визуализации на маленьком экране Vertical Slider Slick

Tags: css3, кроссплатформенность, slider-slick.js

В браузерах Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Yandex на 1080p разрешениях норм, но если разрешение экрана 720p , то начинается веселье, в первых двух все ок, а в последних при выходе из поля формы заполнения, показывается прошлый баг в виде фантома, немного сдвинув слайд, этот слайд пропадает и показывает нормально форму

Ссылка на Репозиторий
https://bitbucket.org/mykillwikiru/slider_mobile/src/master/

Ссылка на сайт
http://m.slider.gulyaevmartinas.ru/